# Error configuring storage on multer

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, multer

estoy usando multer para subir imagens a mi db mongodb atlas

[image: atlas]

trato de apuntarle a la db que estoy usando actualmente en vez de "myFirstDatabase" que es la que me creo cuando lo ejecute

trate de usar uno de los metodos que estaban en la documentacion de multer-gridfs-storage

[image: code]

y me dio el siguiente error:

```
Type 'Db' is not assignable to type 'DbTypes | Promise<DbTypes>'.
  Property 'secondaryOk' is missing in type 'import("C:/Users/tomas/Documents/GitHub/MateAndMeetBackHeroku/mateandmeetback/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").Db' but required in type 'import("C:/Users/tomas/Documents/GitHub/MateAndMeetBackHeroku/mateandmeetback/node_modules/multer-gridfs-storage/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb").Db'.ts(2322)
mongodb.d.ts(2391, 9): 'secondaryOk' is declared here.
```

Literalmente copie el ejemplo de la documentacion
que puede estar fallando? gracias de antemano

Comment: Estas en [es.so]. Por favor, traduce tu pregunta, gracias

Comment: No copiaste *literalmente*, entre tu código y el de la [documentación](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-gridfs-storage#db) hay diferencias.